# How to use 'the next steps' in a report

Tags: grammaticality

When we are writing a report or a formal article, do we say "The next steps are to ..." or "The next steps are: ..."?

Which one is more formal and suitable for a report?

Comment: It depends on what style you're using throughout the report.

Answer (score 1):

You can do both:

1. The next steps are to do *this* and then *that*...
2. The next steps are:

   - *doing this...*
   - *doing that...*

Both styles are correct.

Answer (score -1):

Is this some kind of report to senior management, advising them what to do? If so, grammar is almost irrelevant. Your readers do not care about grammar, they want to know what you say they must do (and why). You will lose no points with those readers if your next steps are simple imperatives:
"The next steps are:

1. Assemble a fleet on the Northern coast of Gaul;

   2. Set sail for Britain;
   3. Defeat the natives;
      etc. etc."